# Getting POST method after DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()) even i set the method to GET

Tags: java, post, get

I need to send a request with GET method to server. But, after 
'DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());' this line, when i use 'connection.getRequestMethod()', I am getting method as POST. dont know why.
code is :

```
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        URL url1 = new URL(url);
        LOGGER.info(participant.getTxnLogKey() + " URL...................: " + url1);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        LOGGER.info(participant.getTxnLogKey() + "connection.getRequestMethod().................: " + connection.getRequestMethod());

        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeoutMs);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", StringUtils.substring(url, url.indexOf("//") + 2, url.indexOf("biz") + 3));
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "XXXXXXXXX");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("cache-control", "no-cache");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "" + (request.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        LOGGER.info(participant.getTxnLogKey() + "connection.getRequestMethod().................: " + connection.getRequestMethod());
        /* here, the connection.getRequestMethod() returns GET*/
        DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        LOGGER.info(participant.getTxnLogKey() + "connection.getRequestMethod().................: " + connection.getRequestMethod());
        /* here, the connection.getRequestMethod() returns POST. I need it as GET.*/
        output.writeBytes(request);
        output.flush();
```

When I remove DataoutputStream, I am getting PREMATURE END OF FILE.

Comment: Why are you DataoutputStram can't you use just BufferReader

Comment: BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

Comment: Yes Pradeep, i have used it in my code, but still I was getting Premature end of file exception, which was due to SAX parser i guess. The request length was not appropriate. I have now solved this by somehow adjusting the length and then removed DataOutputStream.

Comment: Sounds good .Glad  you solved it.